# UITableView (grouped style) Background Color

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicolor

I'm trying to set the Backgroundcolor of my grouped tableview to a color with an opacity of 30% - I did this in the Interface Builder. And this is the result:

[image]

- why exactly is the color on the side of the section different than the color in the background? I don't get it.

When I set the opacity to 100% the color looks the same everywhere (as I would expect it...)
I tried to solve this programmatically - with the same result.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.3];
```

I develop for iOS 4.0 with xcode 4.3.3

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your TableView color clear color and  put color in your view which you wish.

Comment: I have a TableViewController inside a NavigationController. So I set the TableView backgroundcolor to clearcolor and set the backgroundcolor in the navigationcontroller to my blue and it worked :-)! Thanks for the advice!